# ¿Cómo comunicar 2 formularios de componentes dinámicos en 1 solo formulario? Vue 2

Tags: vue.js

Primera vez que estoy trabajando con dependencia de componentes, el tema es que el primer componente al seleccionar un ejecutivo me abre el 2do componente que tambien es un formulario por proyecto.

El segundo componente yo selecciono al ejecutivo y puedo dejarlo con la opción default, ahora la pregunta es el  lo pongo en el componente padre y ahi puedo capturar tambien el value del componente hijo o no

Adjunto imagen

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La pregunta ¿Cómo podría enviar ambos formulario como 1 solo formulario?

Adjunto código de ambos componentes.

**Componente 1 Ejecutivo ausentarse**

```
<template>
    <div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-12 colmd-12 col-lg-12">
                <fieldset class="border p-2">
                    <legend class="w-auto">Ejecutivo a ausentarse</legend>
                    <div class="form-row">
                        <div class="form-group col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4 mb-3">
                            <b-form-group
                                id="user_id"
                                label="Ejecutivo"
                            >
                                <b-form-select
                                    v-model="form.user_id"
                                    :options="salesman"
                                    value-field="id"
                                    text-field="name"
                                    @change="viewProjects($event)"
                                >
                                    <template v-slot:first>
                                        <b-form-select-option value="All">Seleccione Ejecutivo</b-form-select-option>
                                    </template>
                                </b-form-select>
                            </b-form-group>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4 mb-3">
                            <b-form-group
                                id="user_id"
                                label="Fecha inicio - Fecha termino"
                            >
                                <date-picker
                                    type="date"
                                    :lang="lang"
                                    placeholder="Seleccione rango de fecha"
                                    v-model="dateRange"
                                    value-type="YYYY-MM-DD"
                                    format="DD-MM-YYYY"
                                    :disabled-date="disabledDays"
                                    range
                                @change="searchByDates($event)"
                                ></date-picker>
                            </b-form-group>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4 mb-3">
                            <b-form-group
                                id="reason_absece_id"
                                label="Razón de ausencia"
                            >
                                <b-form-select
                                    v-model="form.reason_absence_id"
                                    :options="absences"
                                    value-field="id"
                                    text-field="name"
                                >
                                    <template v-slot:first>
                                        <b-form-select-option value="All">Seleccione</b-form-select-option>
                                    </template>
                                </b-form-select>
                            </b-form-group>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </fieldset>
            </div>
        </div>
            <projects-user
                :user="form.user_id"
            ></projects-user>

    </div>
</template>

<script>
import DatePicker from 'vue2-datepicker'
import 'vue2-datepicker/index.css'
import es from  'vue2-datepicker/locale/es'
import ProjectsUser from './ProjectsUserComponent'

export default {
    name: 'LicensePage',
    components: {
        DatePicker,ProjectsUser
    },
    props: {
    },
    data() {
        return {
            lang: es,
            dateRange: [],
            date_begin: null,
            date_end: null,
            showClose: false,
            salesman: [],
            absences: [],
            form: {
                user_id: 'All',
                daterange:null,
                reason_absence_id: 'All'
            },
        }
    },
    created() {
        this.getSalesman()
        this.getAbsence()
    },
    methods: {
        disabledDays(date){
            const today = new Date()
            return date < today
        },
        async getSalesman(){
            const { data } = await axios.get(route('users.employees_active'))
            this.salesman = data
        },
        async getAbsence(){
            const { data } = await axios.get(route('absences'))
            this.absences = data
        },
        viewProjects(event){
            this.user_id = event
        }
    },
}
</script>
```

**Componente 2, listado de Proyectos**

```
<template >
    <div>
        <div v-show="showProject != false" >
            <template v-if="projects.length === 0">
                <div class="container mt-2">
                    <h5 class="font-weight-normal">Usuario no pertenece a ningún proyecto.</h5>
                </div>
            </template>
            <template v-else>
                <skeleton
                    v-if="loadingProjects === true"
                ></skeleton>
                <div class="row" v-else>
                    <div class=" col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6" v-for="(project, index) in projects" :key="index">
                        <fieldset class="border p-2 col-11">
                            <legend class="w-auto col-12">Proyecto: {{project.name}} {{project.id}}</legend>
                            <b-form-group
                                id="user_id"
                                label="Reemplazante"
                            >
                                    <b-form-select
                                        value="All"
                                        :options="project.users"
                                        value-field="replacement_user_id"
                                        text-field="replacement_user_name"
                                        @change="addReemplacemet($event,project.id)"
                                    >
                                        <template v-slot:first>
                                            <b-form-select-option value="All">Seleccione</b-form-select-option>
                                        </template>
                                    </b-form-select>
                                    <input type="hidden" name="project" id="project" value="project.id">
                                        
                                <small>Si deja en la primera opción todos los ejecutivos del proyecto prodrán visualizar los prospectos.</small>
                            </b-form-group>
                        </fieldset>
                    </div>

                    {{ formProject }}
                </div>
            </template>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
import skeleton from './skeleton/ProjectUserSkeleton.vue'

export default {
    name: 'ProjectsUser',
    components: { skeleton },
    props:{
        user: { type: String },
    },
    data() {
        return {
            user_id: null,
            showProject: false,
            projects: [],
            loadingProjects: true,
            formProject: []
        }
    },
    watch: {
        user: function() {
            this.viewProjects(this.user)
        }
    },
    methods: {
        viewProjects(user){
            if (user != 'All') {
                this.user_id = user
                this.showProject = true
                this.getProjects(this.user_id)
            }else{
                this.user_id = null
                this.showProject = false
                this.projects = []
            }
        },
        async getProjects(salesman){
            this.formProject = []
            this.loadingProjects = true
            await axios.get(route('users.getProjects'),{ 
                params: {
                    filter_user: salesman
                }
             })
                .then((res)=>{
                    this.projects = res.data.data

                    setTimeout(() => {
                        this.loadingProjects = false
                    }, 800);
                })
        },
        addReemplacemet(event,project)
        {
            console.log('ingreso: '+ event+ ' project: '+project)
            var objectP = this.formProject.find(elem => elem.project_id == project)
            
            if (typeof(objectP) !== 'undefined') {
               this.formProject.splice(this.formProject.findIndex(elem => elem.project_id == project),1)
            }
            this.formProject.push({ project_id: project, reemplacement_id:event})
        }
    },
}
</script>
```

Comment: "Cómo podría enviar ambos formulario como 1 solo formulario" que? a donde? usa un store y guarda toda la info en un solo lugar....

Comment: Osea son 2 componentes y cada componente tiene para formulario, el tema que quiero enviar los datos de ambos formularios en 1 solo FORM y nunca he trabajado asi es una duda que me surje ahora porque solo logro capturar datos del formulario padre y no del hijo. Voy a investigar lo del STORE

Comment: "solo logro capturar datos del formulario padre" al hacer una llamada axios, vos llenas el data.. no entiendo porque no podrias tener todos los datos.. o tu tema es que no sabes como pasar datos de un hijo a un padre...

Comment: No se pasar los datos seleccionados del componente hijo al padre

Comment: entonces, mira como cambio tu duda, a como pasar datos de un hijo a un padre... que no lo escribiste por ningun lado.. y ya esta contestado en el sitio.. ahora te busco esa pregunta..

Comment: y esa busqueda en internet, daba millones de hits ;)